# How to list all classes implementing a interface using ReSharper?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

Is there a way to list all classes implementing a given interface in ReSharper?

I usually find ",interfacename" to accomplish that but it is not a terrible solution.

Answer (score 0):

In Resharper you can use [Go to Implementation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/10.0/Navigation_and_Search__Go_to_Implementation.html?origin=old_help) (`Ctrl+F12`, or click the symbol holding `Ctrl+Alt` keys) and use "Show in Find Results" option to show the results in the find results window.

Not resharper related, but Visual Studio 2015 after [Update 1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2015/11/30/whats-new-in-visual-studio-update-1-for-net-managed-languages/) allows you to right click the interface and select "Go To Implementation". With Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 they have added a shortcut `Ctrl+F12`.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, put the text caret on the interface name and invoke [Go to Derived Symbols](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/10.0/Navigation_and_Search__Go_to_Inheritor.html?origin=old_hel) - either <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, depending on the keyboard scheme.

Note that you can also hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> on the interface name and type "derived" to get to the Go to Derived Symbols action a little quicker. Or use the [Navigate To context menu](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/10.0/Navigation_and_Search__Navigate_from_Here.html?origin=old_help) to show all the navigation options for the interface name (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>~</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>)

Also, when the popup menu shows listing the interfaces, click the icon in the top right, and it will open the list in the Find Results window.